# Get DateTime on querystring

Tags: c#, datetime, query-string

there are 2 variable in my querystring:

```
&Start=Mon Apr 02 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0200&End=Thu Apr 26 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0200
```

when i try to get it

like this:

```
DateTime EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["End"]);
```

or this:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.QueryString["Start"], "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat);
```

i got the message :
The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Anybody can help me?

PS: i use devexpress Component

```
 <dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="ASPxDateEdit_Synthe_Fin" runat="server" Width="100px" ClientInstanceName="ASPxDateEdit_Synthe_Fin">
                                                 </dx:ASPxDateEdit>

  <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton_Synthese" runat="server" Text="Synthese" AutoPostBack="False">
                             <ClientSideEvents Click="function (s, e) { e.processOnServer = false; window.open('Report/Syntehse.aspx?CientID='+ASPxComboBox_Client.GetValue()+'&Start='+ASPxDateEdit_Synth_Deb.GetValue()+'&End='+ASPxDateEdit_Synthe_Fin.GetValue());}" />
                        </dx:ASPxButton>
```

[image]
[image]

Thanks you in advance

Comment: if you look at the format string you pass to `ParseExact` you should see right away why this fails.

Comment: What format are you sending in the querystring? The in start you say `Mon Apr 02 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0200`, later in the screenshot it says `Mon Apr 02 2012 00:00:00 GMT 0200`

Answer (score 1):

why do you write `"dd/MM/yyyy"` ? it aint the format in the QS ...

it should be something like :

```
ddd MMM  dd yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

--->Mon Apr 02 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0200

Comment: Also, where are you getting your input date from? I'd recommend to stick to the ISO-8601 date format whenever possible to avoid running into annoying date formatting issues.

Comment: @oded yeah thats why i wrote `something like` ... just to tell im what is the direction. im just looking for the time part....

Answer (score 1):

`Convert` will try different formats, but can fail, as you have seen.

When using `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` you need to pass in a format string that *directly* corresponds to the string you are trying to parse.

You have use `dd/MM/yyyy` for `Mon Apr 02 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0200`. These do not correspond to each other.

Try `ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss G\MTK` instead:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Mon Apr 02 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0200", 
                    "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss G\\MTK",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

---

Update:

An additional issue is that the URL parameters are not URL encoded so this:

```
&Start=Mon Apr 02 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0200&End=Thu Apr 26 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0200
```

End up with the `+` characters being seen as spaces on the server side (since `+` also encodes a space on URLs).

You need to URL encode the date/time values before placing them on the URL.

Comment: Thanks you, i try 'DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.QueryString["Start"], "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss G\\MTK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);' but still got the same message

Comment: @user609511 - What _exactly_ does `Request.QueryString["Start"]` look like when you get the error?

Comment: @user609511 - I didn't ask for the exception or the errors. I asked, what is the value of `Request.QueryString["Start"]` when you get the error.

Comment: @user609511 - That's on the URL. What is it on the server side?

Comment: @user609511 - You will note that in the server side, the `GMT+0200` has turned into `GMT 0200`. Note the missing `+`. You really should be URL encoding before putting _anything_ on the URL (or at least replace the `+` with `%2B` on the URL).

Comment: thanks but still not working:  DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.QueryString["Start"].Replace("+", "%2B"), "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss G\\MTK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: @user609511 - You are doing the replace _on the server side_. This needs to be done _before the values are on the URL_.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss \"GMT\"zzz", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) works on the format specified in the querystring.